# Taking number between two specific characters

Tags: mysql

I have a link like the following

```
https://www.example.com/xy-pz-p123456789.html
```

From this link I would like to extract the number '123456789' using mysql query.

I have the following query to extract everything after the last -p

```
SELECT id, RIGHT(`internal_id`,LOCATE('p',reverse(`internal_id`)) - 1) from pricing_dm where `id` = 1
```

The query returns: 123456789.html

I have the following query to get everything left of ".html"

```
SELECT id, left(`internal_id`,LOCATE('.html',`internal_id`) - 1) from pricing_dm where `id` = 1
```

The query returns https://www.example.com/xy-pz-p123456789

Is there a way how I can combine these two in one query to only extract the number.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a Query like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX('https://www.example.com/xy-pz-p123456789.html', '-p', -1), '.' ,1);
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    ->  SUBSTRING_INDEX('https://www.example.com/xy-pz-p123456789.html', '-p', -1), '.' ,1);
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX(
 SUBSTRING_INDEX('https://www.example.com/xy-pz-p123456789.html', '-p', -1), '.' ,1) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 123456789                                                                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a regular expression

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Something like `mysql> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('internal_id', '(.*)\d*\(.html)');` (.*)\d*.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySql casting trick:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oC7zRWks24b4QCS4B3RoA1/0

```
SELECT RIGHT(`internal_id`,LOCATE('p',reverse(`internal_id`)) - 1)+0
FROM pricing_dm
```